# Unable to switch between organizations

Tags: ibm-cloud, organization

I am part of two Organizations on Bluemix, however I am unable to switch between those. Interestingly, I see only one Organization listed with my account on Bluemix.

These are the Orgs that I am part of: 
org IBM_CDS_DevOps_org and jdominic@in.ibm.com.

However I do not see the org jdominic@in.ibm.com listed with my account and I am unable to switch either. Apparently, I am able to push code to the organization that is not listed using cloud foundry.

"Showing health and status for app JPD_Controller in **org jdominic@in.ibm.com** / space dev as jdominic@in.ibm.com...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first I suggest you should double check that you have been invited to the jdominic@in.ibm.com org and that the org owner gave you the correct roles.

Since you are correctly accessing the org using the CF CLI I suggest you to double check that the environment you are referring to using the CLI is the same you are accessing via browser.